# How to add a fix symbol in TextInput which remains static when the uses enters something (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I've a text box to enter username. And I want a @ symbol at the beginning of this `TextInput`. Also, this @ symbol shouldn't be able to be removed.

[image]
How can I make @ symbol static here? `defaultValue` won't help me in my case.

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot attach content on input's pseudo-classes `::before` and `::after`,
you should wrap your `<input>` into a `<label>`, and put the '@' symbol on the `label::before`

```
<label id="my-input">
  <input />
</label>

<style>
#my-input::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "@";
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLg0d3jv/

Answer (score 1):

It will be optimal to use 2 different components, first element with static symbol "@" and second is Text input: `<Text>@</Text>` and `<TextInput/>`

Comment: Please add the styles as you want. You can see it as an example: [link](https://snack.expo.io/@evgeniy/text-input)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use basic css for this. 
I got this example from the fiddle, may be this is what you want.

HTML

```
<div class="input-icon">
  <input type="text" placeholder="0.00">
  <i>$</i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-icon {
  position: relative;
}

.input-icon > i {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
}

.input-icon > input {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your TextInput inside a View component and place an Image at the very beginning. I once created something similar like this

```
    <View
        style={{
            flex: 1,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 11,
            borderColor: "#e1e1e1",
        }}>
        <TextInput
            placeholder="Place Enter Your Username"
            placeholderTextColor={'#FFFFFF'}
            style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}
            underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
                this.filter = text
            }}/>
        <Image
            resizeMode={'cover'}
            style={{
                width: 22,
                height: 24,
                marginRight: 25,
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 10,
                top: 10
            }}
            source={require('./Images/ic_search_color.png')}/>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend your `Input` component to have this functionality. Something like

```
const extendedInput = (props) => (
  <div>
    <span>@</span>
    <input {...props} />
  </div>
)
```